# Adding spacing around text in Conky?

Tags: conky

I've created a pretty awesome layout in Conky for my desktop machine.

[image: case in point]

I'm unfortunately having a hard time trying to add padding to the text on the right to separate the right side of the text from the right border.

Here's my configuration:

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont 123:size=8
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 0.5
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_type panel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
minimum_size 270 1080
#maximum_width 450
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color white
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color black 
alignment top_left
gap_x 0
gap_y 0 
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
use_spacer left
override_utf8_locale yes

lua_load ~/.config/conky/scripts/conky_lua_scripts.lua

TEXT
${image .conky/mightymoose-sidebar-background.png}${image .conky/mightymoose-logo.png -p 10,10 -s 255x100}${voffset 110}
${offset 10}${font Monospace:bold:size=8}PROCESSORS ${hr 2}
${font Monospace:size=8}${cpugraph cpu0 30,255 333333 FFFFFF}
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu1 6,135}$alignr ${execi 1 get-i7z-value freq -c 0}  ${execi 1 get-i7z-value temp -c 0} ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu1}}%
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu2 6,135}$alignr ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu2}}%
${offset 10}${voffset -5}${hr 0.1}
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu3 6,135}$alignr ${execi 1 get-i7z-value freq -c 1}  ${execi 1 get-i7z-value temp -c 1} ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu3}}%
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu4 6,135}$alignr ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu4}}%
${offset 10}${voffset -5}${hr 0.1}
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu5 6,135}$alignr ${execi 1 get-i7z-value freq -c 2}  ${execi 1 get-i7z-value temp -c 2} ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu5}}%
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu6 6,135}$alignr ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu6}}%
${offset 10}${voffset -5}${hr 0.1}
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu7 6,135}$alignr ${execi 1 get-i7z-value freq -c 3}  ${execi 1get-i7z-value temp -c 3} ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu7}}%
${offset 10}${cpubar cpu8 6,135}$alignr ${lua_parse format %3.0f ${cpu cpu8}}%

${offset 10}${font Monospace:bold:size=8}MEMORY ${hr 2}
${offset 10}${font Monospace:size=8}${membar}
${offset 10}$alignc${mem} of ${memmax}: ${lua_parse format %3.0f $memperc}%

${offset 10}${font Monospace:bold:size=8}GPU ${hr 2}
${offset 10}${font Monospace:size=8}Temperature:$alignr${nvidia temp}°C
${offset 10}GPU Frequency:$alignr${nvidia gpufreq} MHz
${offset 10}Memory Frequency:$alignr${nvidia memfreq} MHz

${offset 10}${font Monospace:bold:size=8}NETWORK ${hr 2}
${offset 10}${font Monospace:size=8}eth0:  ${addr eth0}$alignr${font :size=8}↑${font Monospace:size=6}${upspeedf eth0}${font :size=8}↓${font Monospace:size=6}${downspeedf eth0}${font :size=8}
${offset 10}${font Monospace:size=8}wlan0: ${addr eth2}$alignr${font :size=8}↑${font Monospace:size=6}${upspeedf eth2}${font :size=8}↓${font Monospace:size=6}${downspeedf eth2}${font :size=8}
${offset 10}${font :size=20}↓${downspeedgraph eth2 25,105 333333 FFFFFF -l}↑${upspeedgraph eth2 25,105 333333 FFFFFF -l}
```

It seems pretty silly to have to specify an offset on each line to move everything to the right 10px, but if it's the only solution, that's okay.

The main goal here is to add 10px of spacing to the right side to pull the text away from the right border. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the config settings for [border_inner_margin](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html)...

Comment: Just tested out border_inner_margin, seems to do what I believe OP is looking for. @jasonwryan, I think you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conky has an [absurdly comprehensive array of settings](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html) for displaying your system information.

The two that would be of most interest in this case are:

- border_inner_margin
- border_outer_margin

In the situation that you have described, I would suggest the former:

> Inner border margin in pixels (the margin between the border and text).